# obiee 11g catalog cleanup

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

I want to cleanup users folder in obiee catalog. There are 22885 items in the users catalog but the number of bi developers and end users is about 500.  I mean, there are a huge number of deactive user folder in the catalog. How can i find the active users among the all user folders.

For example:
the users folder contains the following folders >>>
username1
username2
.
.
.
.
.
username22885

but username2 left from the company and its user deleted from the company domain but still its user folder exist in the catalog/users folder. I want to find all of this kind of users and delete their folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get a list of users which aren't active anymore (or which are still active, whatever is shorter), then you can use the runcat.sh/cmd command line to script deletion of any object or objects that you want based on that list.

Runcat is nothing but the core command behind catalog manager where you have to do things manually one by one.